# Scala matching list

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to get first and last element from and `List` of `Int`s. Here is what I am trying now:

```
def find(lista: List[Integer]) : (Int,Int) = {
    case (x) => (x,x)
    case (x1,x2) => (x2,x2)
    case hd :: _ :: tail => find(tail)   
}
```

I am getting an warning in line `find(tail)`:

```
type mismatching found List[Any], required List[Integer]
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're receiving? Is it a `MatchError`? Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, unless this is an academic exercise, why not try `(lista.head, lista.last)`?

Comment: I know it is possible I just want to do it without that lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you've missed the `match` statement in your code i.e. it should be,

```
def find(lista: List[Int]): (Int, Int) = lista match {
  //cases go here
}
```

You've also got some extractor issues (tuples don't match `List`)
 so the first few case statements should be,

```
{
  case h :: Nil => (h, h)
  case h1 :: h2 :: Nil => (h1, h2)
  ...
}
```

What you've actually done in missing the `match` is made scala convert a `PartialFunction` into a `Function`. The reason it infererred the input type to `Any` is because the first two `case` statements matched tuples rather than `List` hence it widened the type to `Any`.

The final code is,

```
def find(lista: List[Int]) : (Int,Int) = lista match {
    case h :: Nil => (h, h)
    case h1 :: h2 :: Nil => (h1, h2)
    case hd :: _ :: tail => find(tail)
 }
```

Comment: :) find(List(1,2,3,4)) == (3,4) ; find(List(1,2,3)) == (3,3) ; find(List(1,2)) ==  (1,2)

Comment: @nikiforo You're right - I didn't actually bother reading the actual point of the function just translated what had been written.

Answer (score 2):

Here you match against a tuple:

```
case (x1,x2) => (x2,x2)
```

If you want to play with recursion and pattern matching you can do smth like:

```
object HeadTail{
  def find(lista: List[Int]) : (Int,Int) = {
    @tailrec
    def getLast(l: List[Int]): Int = l match {
      case h :: Nil => h
      case h :: tail => getLast(tail)
    }

    lista match {
      case Nil => throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty list")
      case h :: tail => (h, getLast(lista))
    }
  }
}
```

Here how it works:

```
scala> stackoverflow.q35804673.HeadTail.find(List(1,2,3,4,5))
res0: (Int, Int) = (1,5)

scala> stackoverflow.q35804673.HeadTail.find(List(1,5))
res1: (Int, Int) = (1,5)

scala> stackoverflow.q35804673.HeadTail.find(List(1))
res2: (Int, Int) = (1,1)

scala> stackoverflow.q35804673.HeadTail.find(List.empty)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty list
```